# Invoke function parameter as part of ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to pass a URL parameter to AngularJS controller using below code :

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl" ng-init="init(getParameter('myParam'))">  
  </div>
</div>

function TodoCtrl($scope) {

     $scope.init = function(category)
      {
        $scope.category = category;

        alert(category);
      };

}

function getParameter(theParameter) { 
          var params = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');

          for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            var p=params[i].split('=');
            if (p[0] == theParameter) {
              return decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
            }
          }
          return false;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15042?myParam=test

But it appears the function `getParameter('myParam')` is not being invoked correctly I expect `alert(category);` to display 'test' but instead it displays `undefined`.

How to pass a URL parameter to AngularJS controller ?

Update :

Here is solution I went with :

```
alert(gup('category' , $location.absUrl()))

function getParameter( name, url ) {

      name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
      var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
      var results = regex.exec( url );
      return results == null ? null : results[1];
    }
```

Url is of form http://xxx.xxx.xxx?category=test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ng-init for anything but aliasing special properties of ng-repeat, see the ng-init docs for details.  Instead if you need to read something from the URL parameters you can use $routeParams or $stateParams if you're using ngRoute or ui-router respectively or use $location.search

Answer (score 1):

Angular has built in helpers for reading and setting the url. In this case, use `$location.search()`: (note that this snippet will only work on a page where the parameter is set!)

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope, $location) {
  var param = $location.search().myParam;
  if(param) {
    $scope.category = param;
    alert(param);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, I "fake" set the parameter so you can see it in action:

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope, $location) {
  $location.search('myParam', 'myValue')
  var param = $location.search().myParam;
  if(param) {
    $scope.category = param;
    alert(param);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  </div>
</div>
```